# Sticky menu bar “jumps”/flicker while scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, menu

I'm using myStick Header Menu wordpress plugin and I tried a lot combinations at css style field but it keep "jump" when scroll donw... http://www.ineditus.com.br

there is a way to solve it using the css style field from mystick header plugin? tnks

the last code that I tried:

```
#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: 99990;
    -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition: 1.2s;
    -o-transition: 1.2s;
    transition: 1.2s;
    filter: alpha(opacity=94);
    opacity: 0.94;
    background-color: #23007c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the margins for your site. Usually, an issue with margins can cause the jumping. Here is link [that describes the issue more on WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sticky-header-jumping-effect/)